# Windows 8 won't boot after Boot Repair

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, multi-boot, bootrepair

I've got a Sony Vaio laptop. Until yesterday I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed. Today I upgraded to Windows 8, which killed my OS selection screen. So I booted to Ubuntu 12.10 from a USB stick and ran Boot Repair. This recovered the GRUB screen and let me boot into my Ubuntu 12.04 installation, but now I can' boot Windows 8.

When I select the option that booted Windows 7 before, it looks like it wants to start Windows 7 (sic) again (black screen, with the text "Windows is loading" or something), but then reboots the machine after a few seconds.

I'm sure Boot Repair can fix this, but I know far too little about the whole booting thing to know the right settings for it.

Here's [my boot repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1308117/) thing.

**Edit:** I really want to emphasize that it seems to be trying to start Windows 7. I'm pretty sure Boot Repair selected some old Windows 7 backup files. I already ran Boot Repair once after I installed Ubuntu. Maybe it's using some files or configs it created back then.

Comment: For future reference, if you have a question on another site that would be a better fit somewhere else, flag it on the original site so we don't have duplicates coming over

Comment: Since you seem to be using an EFI booting environment, the problem could be caused by secure boot or EFI booting. What was the option you chose when you did the boot repair?

Comment: I used the big "Auto" button. So I have no idea what it actually did. it seems to me like I have to edit some "boot file" or whatever manually. The (failing) Windows boot looks like it wants to start Windows 7. So maybe something points to an old Win7 "boot file" or whatever. Again, I have no idea how booting a computer actually works, so excuse my sloppy words..

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Here is how I fixed it:

1. UEFI booted a USB flash drive which contained the Windows 8 installer.
2. Clicked Install and chose Custom.
3. Deleted all System, MSR and Recovery partitions.
4. Selected the OS partition and clicked Install.
5. It showed a message that setup will now create system partitions, I clicked OK and it recreated the EFI bootloader again.
6. Ran the following commands one-by-one in Command Prompt: `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, `bootrec /rebuildbcd`